# How can I catch an EHOSTDOWN socket error when creating an http request with iojs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, http

I have a simple iojs http server which communicates with another http backend on my development machine. Now my ip has changed and the backend request won't work due to a wrong ip. I have (or at least thought so) error management in place however the server crashes in some situations due to an unhandled exception:

When doing 2 subsequent requests the first one "hangs" and then the second request crashes the server:

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: connect EHOSTDOWN 192.168.1.11:80 - Local (192.168.1.10:54125)
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:846:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:869:20)
    at connect (net.js:840:14)
    at lookupAndConnect (net.js:933:5)
    at Socket.connect (net.js:902:5)
    at Agent.exports.connect.exports.createConnection (net.js:61:35)
    at Agent.createSocket (_http_agent.js:177:16)
    at Agent.addRequest (_http_agent.js:147:23)
    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:132:16)
    at Object.exports.request (http.js:30:10)
```

The error in question won't trigger `backRequest.on("error", errFn)` and it is not a standard error as in `function(err, response, body)`. It can't be catched using try...catch.

How can i catch and gracefully handle this error?

I have dugged a bit into net.js/http.js. When emitting a socket error manually:

```
backendRequest.on("socket", function(socket) {
    socket.emit("error", "DIE!");
});
```

it is handled by the normal error handler. The EHOSTDOWN error however is not. The reason for this seems to be that the socket error handler is only installed on the next tick after Socket.connect() (see https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/_http_client.js#L498).

"My" error however is triggered directly upon connect() (must have something to do with the first connection still trying to find the host).

I can gracefully catch that error using a custom Agent.createConnection:

```
var socket = net.createConnection(options);
// install error handler immediately
socket.on("error", function(err) {
    console.log("AHA", err);
});
return socket;
```

however that seems very verbose and bulky. Is that truly the best way to do that? The error seems to be not that special and seems to be unhandled in the core libs. Why is that so and why is the socket error handler only installed upon nextTick?

How would you properly catch that error? Is the agent the correct way?

A "full" example to play with can be found here: http://pastebin.com/jaCUPaHX

Comment: This appears to be a bug and is being addressed: https://github.com/nodejs/io.js/pull/2054

Comment: Yep, fixed in https://github.com/nodejs/io.js/commit/af249fa8a15bad8996187e73b480b30dcd881bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by the commenters: It was a bug https://github.com/nodejs/io.js/pull/2054